# CKEditor loading file that does not and has never existed on my system

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm running a site locally through Visual Studio, CK Editor v4.7.2. The URL of the CK Editor config file is `http://localhost:61299/plugins/ckeditor/config.js`. Loading that page manually loads the file as expected:

[image: correct file]

When CK Editor runs, however, it's loading something entirely different:

[image: invalid file]

This file is being loaded based on the URL parameter. Changing the parameter to anything else loads the original file. I am not appending the parameter, the library seems to be doing it.

The fun part? This file does not and has never existed on my system, anywhere. It's not a caching issue either.

[image: search results window with zero results]

What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

vaindil

If whatever reason CKEditor could not load config.js, it uses default temp configuration generated in ckeditor.js (if I'm not mistaken)

If your question, why CKEditor not load yours, most reasons will be in your file permissions, file path or js error/wrong configuration (even i didn't see any errors in your config)